# Product design pattern library

Tags: guidelines, pattern-library

I'm working internally with a large in-house team to establish an in-house pattern library for just UX designers at this stage.
I'm compiling a list of best practice examples that I have shared below.
Do you know of any other examples that you have in your bookmarks?
I'm focusing on product design, not style guides.

You can see the list I have compiled here:
https://www.evernote.com/l/AroYdCN1aiJC-LpjSiI7LEhssSJNBtsU3mw

Answer (score 0):

I have another two links hope this will helpful.

http://ui-patterns.com/patterns

http://www.colorion.co/popular

Comment: Can you please paraphrase the info at those sites (eg. by copying the main points, quoting, taking screenshots etc)? That way if those links become broken the answer will still be useful to future readers?